# Javascript DataTable unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, datatable

my datatable gives me that error. (Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4). how can i change that ? In DataTable i can see the rows but not data text .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AXR7.png)

how can i fix this ?

My Html

```
<table id="callback_table" class="table manage_table" style="width: 100%;">
                        <thead id="callbackTable">
                            <tr>
                                <th>@ResourceManager.GetResource("Id")</th>
                                <th>@ResourceManager.GetResource("CallbackDate")</th>
                                <th style="width: 200px">@ResourceManager.GetResource("PointExpiryDate")</th>
                                <th style="width: 200px">@ResourceManager.GetResource("Point")</th>
                                <th>@ResourceManager.GetResource("TaskId")</th>
                                <th>@ResourceManager.GetResource("CallbackType")</th>
                                <th>@ResourceManager.GetResource("TaskName")</th>
                                <th>@ResourceManager.GetResource("Status")</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tdata">
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

My JS

```
var jsonData;
$.ajax({
    url: '/History/GetCallbackHistory?' + "UserId" + "=" + document.getElementById("callbackuserid").value ,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data); 
    }
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#callback_table').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/History/GetCallbackHistory?' + "UserId" + "=" + document.getElementById("callbackuserid").value,
            "type": "GET",
            "dataSrc": function (json) {
                console.log(json);
                return json;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My JSON

```
[
{
"Id": 6,
"TaskId": 302,
"Point": 4,
"DateCallback": "30-05-2020 12:02:29",
"DateEnd": "30-05-2020 12:02:29",
"callbackId": 2,
"Status": 1,
"callbackStatus": 0,
"phoneNumber": null,
"Task_name": ""
},
{},
{
"Id": 8,
"TaskId": 6459,
"Point": 10,
"DateCallback": "19-02-2021 14:25:08",
"DateEnd": "21-03-2021 14:25:08",
"callbackId": 2,
"Status": 1,
"callbackStatus": 0,
"phoneNumber": null,
"Task_name": ""
},
{
"Id": 9,
"TaskId": 6459,
"Point": 10,
"DateCallback": "19-02-2021 15:32:30",
"DateEnd": "21-03-2021 15:32:30",
"callbackId": 2,
"Status": 1,
"callbackStatus": 0,
"phoneNumber": null,
"Task_name": ""
},
{
"Id": 37,
"TaskId": 6784,
"Point": 5,
"DateCallback": "01-04-2021 12:58:49",
"DateEnd": "11-04-2021 19:06:44",
"callbackId": 8,
"Status": 1,
"callbackStatus": 0,
"phoneNumber": null,
"Task_name": ""
}
]
```

Comment: I think there may be more than one problem in your code. But one obvious problem is in your JSON, where you have an empty object: `{ }`. That will cause the "_Requested unknown parameter _" warning. Also, another _potential_ problem is that you have a `dataSrc` function which does not do anything, except to assign your JSON to a new variable (`json`). Do you need that?  Why not just use `dataSrc: ''`?

Comment: If you have not already done so, you can take the [tour] and read [ask]. The error message provides a link to a web page containing detailed notes about how to diagnose and resolve this general problem. What have you tried from that page?